# Set maxHeight for javafx alert with scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I have a javafx alert which has a ScrollPane. Inside the ScrollPane I am loading a gridpane whose size can vary depending on content. So the alert grows with the content of the GridPane. I am using the GridPane to prevent the alert from exceeding the apps screen size and allow scrolling. But this is not working. Instead the alert is growing to beyond the size that I have set.

Here is my code:

```
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
scroll.setContent(gridpane);
scroll.setMaxHeight(500);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(scroll);
```

where alert is an instance of the javafx Alert class and the gridpane has content which is added dynamically.

The `gridpane` is an instance of `CustomGrid` which is defined as follows:

```
  public class CustomGrid extends GridPane{

    public CustomGrid() {
        this.setHgap(20);
        this.setVgap(20);

        ColumnConstraints firstColConstraints =  new ColumnConstraints();
        firstColConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        firstColConstraints.setPercentWidth(50.0);
        firstColConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        ColumnConstraints secondColConstraints =  new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints thirdColConstraints =  new ColumnConstraints();
        thirdColConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        this.getColumnConstraints().addAll(firstColConstraints, secondColConstraints, thirdColConstraints);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [`prefViewportHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#prefViewportHeightProperty).

Comment: @Michael Thanks. This makes all the alerts the same size (500). I want the alert to be able to grow in height but only to a certain extent i.e. I don't want it to go over 500.

Comment: You say "it is not working", what does that mean?  In what way does it not work as you expected?

Comment: @jewelsea The alert is not bounded by this max height and grows beyond it.

Comment: So far it's not clear what are the exact symptoms that you are seeing. Does the height of alert exceed 500px only when your contents in GridPane grow beyond 500px tall? If true, does your ScrollPane display the vertical scrollbar? Does your ScrollPane show all the >500px tall content, or clips its contents? A screenshot would make it very clear, though.

Comment: @Jai Yes the alert exceeds 500px when contents of the GridPane grow beyond 500px (nothing is clipped). The scrollpane does display a scrollbar but it doesn't scroll a lot because the alert has already grown to accommodate the gridpane.

Comment: Could you please tell about your case more specific? FYI, I've just created a JavaFX 8 project, copied your code, put inside a `GridPane` `TextArea` object with a dummy multiline text - and got an alert 500px height with a long scrolling - just the same you want to get here. So, the question is: what do you put inside your `gridpane` that makes an alert exceed 500px height? What version of JavaFX do you use, is `alert` an instance of `Alert` class?

Comment: @user3552551, what operating system and what version of JDK (including update revision) do you use? Alerts behaviour can differ on different OS.

Comment: @arcquim  I am using mac OS and java 8 version.